# How to add many buttons dynamically giving a line jump before arriving at the edge in Android?

Tags: android, android-button, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add many button into `Relativelayout` or `Linearlayout`,

**Layout**

```
<Relativelayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            >
</Relativelayout>
```

then in the class

```
_ll_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
```

I only know how add the button dynamically with code.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(tmp.getString("productos"));
Button bt[] = new Button[jsonArray.length()]; // size of product
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i ++){
    int padding_40dp = (int) (40 * scale + 0.5f);
    int margin_10dp = (int) (10 * scale + 0.5f);
    int padding_90dp = (int) (90 * scale + 0.5f);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new Relativelayout.LayoutParams(padding_90dp, padding_40dp);
    params.setMargins(margin_10dp, 0 , 0, 0);
    bt[i] = new Button(DetalleServicioActivity.this);
    bt[i].setText(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre"));
    bt[i].setTag(new TagInfo(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_producto")));
    bt[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    bt[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D8D8D8"));
    bt[i].setEnabled(false);
    bt[i].setId(Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_producto")));
    bt[i].setLayoutParams(params);
    _ll_layout.addView(bt[i]);
}
```

but the result is

[image]

One on another one, but I need something like this:

[image]

### **Edit**

If I use `LinearLayout` with orientation `horizontal` and gravity `center`, this happend

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `Relative Layout` or `Linear Layout` I would rather suggest you to create custom `flow layout`.Custom flow layout will adjust child views accordingly in rows, and will jump the button in new row according to screen width.

Please have a look here : [Flow layout example](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hello @zhelon if u r satisfied with this answer u can give bounty to Dory

Comment: @PankajSharma do you know why the child of the flowlayout doenst affected by margen?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of RelativeLayout, make use of LinearLayout with orientation as horizontal and add the button in them at run time

As per your design requirement, make sure you have two linear layouts here.

Comment: If I use that, to a to happen that the buttons are always placed towards the right and cross the edge I say, it because I tried already it

Comment: Set the gravity:center on linearlayout which will keep it center

Comment: Use two linearlayout for each row

Comment: Give me more detail please, I dont understand why do that

Answer (score 0):

you can use [griedlayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) for solved your problem